# Ipython is working in command prompt but not in browser

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using a windows 8 64 bit laptop. I already have python 2.7 on my pc. So I installed Ipython using the easy_install. I can now see an ipython application file in C:\Python27\Scripts. When I run that file it opens up my cmd and I can write code. However when I say `Ipython notebook` in the cmd under the same folder it does not open up the notebook in a browser and gives the following error -

```
C:\Users\UserName>cd C:\Python27\Scripts\

C:\Python27\Scripts>Ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\__init__.p
y", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 544, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\terminal\i
papp.py", line 312, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\core\appli
cation.py", line 373, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\terminal\i
papp.py", line 307, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 474, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\config\app
lication.py", line 405, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\utils\impo
rtstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\html\noteb
ookapp.py", line 36, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\IPython\utils\zmqr
elated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

Comment: I have the same issue on win7. When I type ipython notebook into the cmd line the last line of the output reads ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11. Do you get something similar?

Comment: @Totem You *must* install pyzmp. It is a requierement for ipython

Comment: @joaquin - I tried that command. It is giving me an error. The scrpits forlder has a ipython.exe file only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give the **full** text of any errors or tracebacks you are getting.

Comment: @joaquin - When I execute ipython.exe it just works in the cmd. I want  it to open in the browser.

Comment: What do you get when enter `ipython notebook` ? Include in your question any errors you get

Comment: @joaquin - Added the error traceback in the question

Comment: You **must** install pyzmq

Comment: @joaquin - That worked. Thank You. Do you want to add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @joaquin I found about needing pyzmq through the traceback. However, I couldn't figure out how to install it. I've tried pip install pyzmq, but this doesn't work

Comment: @Totem if you are on windows get if from [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq)

Comment: I have the same problem - `ipython notebook` gives an `ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11`, but with me, I already have pyzmq installed. `pip freeze|grep pyzmq` returns `pyzmq==14.3.1`

Comment: chekck this. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995438/pyzmq-missing-when-running-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The traceback is clear:

You must install **pyzmq**

pyzmq is a requirement for the ipython notebook.
For a list of dependencies [check this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html)

Comment: The strange thing is that `pip install ipython` doesn't install all the dependencies. What use is a package manager when you have to go and do the work yourself?

Comment: If you do a `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` there's no work to do  by yourself. (See the [install documentation](http://ipython.org/install.html)).

Answer (score 14):

### Short answer:

make sure pyzmq is installed in the same virtualenvironment (or lack of) as ipython. For me, ipython notebook was installed as regular, but its dependencies got put in my virtualenvironment. A quick install in the proper place fixed this error for me.

### Long answer:

I'm putting this solution here because the error message is the same though the scenario is different from the original poster's, I think.

I am running iPython notebook in a virtual environment on a virtual box. I think the virtual box bit is irrelevant, but the virtualenvironment is not. I installed ipython[notebook] via pip in the virtualenvironment and got the same error `ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11`

But, I could plainly see that pyzmq *was* installed. Both `pip freeze` and `pip install --upgrade pyzmq` showed that I had the latest pyzmq version available and it was definitely >= 2.1.11 (`pip freeze|grep pyzmq` gives `pyzmq==14.3.1`).

I exited the virtualenvironment and checked pyzmq again and discovered that pyzmq was installed *only* in the virtualenv. That should be the way it's supposed to work, but for some reason ipython was looking in the main python location, not the virtualenv's python location. I suspect that ipython was installed outside the virtualenvironment. I don't know why pyzmq was installed only inside it. Anyhow, `pip install pyzmq` while *outside* my virtualenvironment fixed everything and now it all works. Sorry for the verbose answer.

Comment: I got the same problem. I installed ipython in my global python environment. Then I created a virtualenv with `virtualenvwrapper`. I installed ipython inside that virtualenv, but `which ipython` still pointed to the global ipython. Deactivating and reactivating virtualenv solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The [iPython install documentation](http://ipython.org/install.html) says:

> [...] you can get IPython with pip:
>
> ```
> pip install ipython
> ```
>
> Or if you want to also get the dependencies for the IPython notebook:
>
> ```
> pip install "ipython[notebook]"
> ```