# pyzmq missing when running ipython notebook

Tags: python, pip, ipython, easy-install

I can run iPython, but when I try to initiate a notebook I get the following error:

```
~  ipython notebook                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 563, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 39, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

But as far as I can see, I already have the pyzmq package installed.

```
~ pip install pyzmq            
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyzmq in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-14.3.1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: The answer that worked in my case is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25187899/168740

Answer (score 54):

Arg.  The *ipython* install is a little idiosyncratic.  Here's what I had to do to resolve this:

```
$ pip uninstall ipython
$ pip install "ipython[all]"
```

The issue is that notebooks have their own set of dependencies, which aren't installed with `pip install ipython`.  However, having installed *ipython*, pip doesn't see the need to add anything if you then try the `[all]` form.

As mentioned in comments for some shells (e.g. zsh) it's necessary to escape or quote the square brackets (`pip install ipython\[all\]` would also work).

Comment: This worked for me but I had to also uninstall pyzmq first otherwise the problem persisted.

Comment: `pip install ipython[all]` command fails if the `ipython[all]` part is not wrapped in quotes: see also http://ipython.org/install.html

Comment: Works fine for me. What shell are you using?

Comment: This failed for me as well. Needed `pip install "ipython[all]"` using zsh.

Comment: Well, if you hope to get any further, maybe you could try mentioning what shell and environment you're using?  I have an ipython notebook server running at this very moment that I installed with this.

Comment: Yes, some shells require the quotes; others don't.  Basically, if your shell requires that the '[]' chars be escaped, then you should put it in quotes.  Also, it shouldn't hurt to just always quote it, so for the sake of documentation updating this answer is probably worthwhile :)

Comment: pip install "ipython[all]" worked for me in zsh in Yosemite. Thanks

Comment: `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` is not better?

Comment: define "better".  You don't save a lot, since you need to have the iPython engine and such in any case.

Comment: Solved the same issue for me!!

Answer (score 1):

For me (Ubuntu 14.04.2) worked installation by synaptic package manager: the package is called python3-zmq, with this package will be installed libzmq3.

After that check if pyzmq is correctly installed:

```
pip list
```

Then I installed ipython:

```
pip install "ipython[all]"
```

Comment: For me the problem was that I installed _python-zmq_ instead of _python3-zmq_ (ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
ipython2.7 notebook
```

Instead of

```
ipython notebook
```

Did the trick for me.