# Ipython notebook pyzmq error

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I run ipython notebook; I get "ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13"  error message in console. I already run " pip install "ipython[notebook]" " but I can not run the notebook. Could you pls assist how to solve this issue.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 573, in launch_instance app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 369, in initialize self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error 
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 29, in <module>
check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 12, in check_for_zmq
  raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by,minimum_version))
 ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need the pyzmq package (version >= 13).

You can try installing it (or upgrading if need be) with :

`pip install --upgrade pyzmq`

Comment: I typed _pip install --upgrade pyzmq_ and showed that it has been up to date. "Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq in c:\python27\lib\site-packages"  but it gives the same error. "ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13" @ullullu

Comment: Have you seen this? Have you tried uninstalling pyzmq as well before re-installing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995438/pyzmq-missing-when-running-ipython-notebook

Comment: Are you running in a virtualenv? This might be your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892529/ipython-is-working-in-command-prompt-but-not-in-browser.

Comment: I uninstalled then re install pyzmq, it works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

These works for me ( win8 + anaconda 2.7.10 )

- Uninstall zmq 4.0.4.
- Install zmq 3.2.4.
- pip uninstall ipython
- pip install "ipython[all]"
- pip uninstall pyzmq
- pip install pyzmq